# Magento 1.8.1 how to display layered navigation in a static block like the catergory left navigation?

Tags: magento, layered-navigation, static-block

I would like to display the layered navigation (as per the category left navigation) within a static block without modifying local.xml.

The intention is to convert parent categories into cms pages displaying the layered navigation of its sub-categories instead of having a no products match selection...

I know that a template already exists, being catalog/navigation/left.phtml but I don't know how to call such within the braces:

```
{{block type=""}}
```

Appreciate all the help

With best regards

Fab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The block type is: `catalog/navigation`, so the short-code would be:

```
{{block type="catalog/navigation" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Thanks Axel, that was fast. Just wanted to ask is there a way not to display the products count?

Comment: Yes, simply make a copy of `catalog/navigation/left.phtml` to a different file, say: `catalog/navigation/left-nocounts.phtml` and remove the instance of: `(<?php echo $_category->getProductCount() ?>)` from the new file.  Then set your block code to use that new file: `{{block type="catalog/navigation" template="catalog/navigation/left-nocounts.phtml"}}`